# Show Class name before object in console.log from factory function

Tags: javascript

When I console.log an object that was created from a Class, it shows the name of the class in front of the object in the console. How can I get this to happen when using a factory function and without using a class?

### Chrome

[image: Chrome]

### VSCode via Nodejs

[image: VSCode via Nodejs]

Comment: try function makeCar () {
    return new Car()
}

Comment: You return an empty object from makeCar (`return {}`). Maybe you meant something else? (`return new Car()`).

Comment: If you want to use an object literal, you can't. If you're working with node.js exclusively, you can [customise how objects are displayed](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_custom_inspection_functions_on_objects) though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so (and even add custom attributes to it and specify their properties):

```js
class Car {
  constructor() {}
}

const car = new Car()

console.log(car)

function carFactory() {
  const ret = Object.create(
    Car.prototype, {
      someAddedProp: {
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        value: 'hello'
      },
      someAddedReadOnlyProp: {
        writable: false,
        configurable: true,
        value: "You can't change me!!!"
      },
    }
  );
  return ret;
}

const anotherCar = carFactory();

console.log(anotherCar)
```

**Using Object.create won't invoke the constructor, but you are able to set properties with the second argument to Object.create**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I think you are trying to achieve this:

```
class Car{
   constructor(name){
      this.name = name;
   }
}

console.log("Car:",new Car("ferrari"));

function makeCar(name){
    return new Car(name);
}

console.log("Car:",makeCar("bugatti"));
```